# Undefined variable laravel 4.1

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to get data from database and pass values to controller. I am new at laravel and thats the first query. Here is my code:

```
class Cars extends Eloquent
    {


    }
```

FleetController.php

```
public function index()
    {
           $fleet = Cars::all()->first()->Description;
           return View::make('pages.home')->with('fleet', $fleet);
    }
```

home.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.default')
@section('content')
{{ $fleet }}
@stop
```

The problem is that it shows this at log

Next exception '`ErrorException`' with message

```
'Undefined variable: fleet (View: C:\wamp\www\laravel\app\views\pages\home.blade.php)' in C:\wamp\www\laravel\app\storage\views\7da5cff457f71f3156f90053865b6cb1:2
Stack trace:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try using

```
@if(Session::has('fleet'))
{{Session::get('fleet')}}
@endif
```

Your '->with()' just flashes the variable to your session. You still need to retrieve it from there though.

Also, you should try creating a model with the same name as your table. If you were to create a model Car that extends Eloquent, it will automatically be linked to your Cars table. Laravel docs:

> The lower-case, plural name of the class will be used as the table
>   name unless another name is explicitly specified.

This part is important as well:

> Eloquent will also assume that each table has a primary key column
>   named 'id'.

Once you got that configured, you'll be able to get the description of a car by simple doing

```
Car::all()->first()->description;
```

See also: [Laravel docs on eloquent](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#basic-usage)

**Update**

What *should* work:

**Car.php**

```
class Car extends Eloquent{
//Let's try setting these manually. Make sure they are correct.
protected $table = 'cars';
protected primaryKey = 'id';
}
```

**FleetController.php**

```
public function index()
{ 
//You have to call the model here, so singular 'Car'.
$fleet = Car::all()->first()->Description; 
return View::make('pages.home')->with('fleet', $fleet);
}
```

**home.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.default')
@section('content')
//You can use blade's @if as well:
@if(Session::has('fleet'))
{{Session::get('fleet')}}
@endif
@stop
```

Comment: Editet my question as you said and still doesn't work. Next exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Undefined variable: fleet (View: C:\wamp\www\laravel\app\views\pages\home.blade.php)' in C:\wamp\www\laravel\app\storage\views\7da5cff457f71f3156f90053865b6cb1:2
Stack trace:

Comment: I was trying to create a table and cmd: Generating optimized class loader Compiling common classes and stops here

Comment: @Arual Have you added the if(Session... in your view as well? 
It's btw best if your model is named Car, not Cars and the php is Car.php.
Also, updated my post for some more info on Eloquent models.

Comment: Is ok view this way @extends('layouts.default')
@section('content')
if(Session::has('fleet')
{ 
$fleet = Session::get('fleet'); 
{{ $fleet }}
}
@stop

Comment: Yeah, that seems about right. But that still doesn't work then? What's your table name? Cars? Does it have an 'id' column? What's in your routing.php for the index()?

Comment: Table name is "cars" and it has an id column. app/controllers/CarController.php here is the index().

Comment: and I named model>Car.php. Connection with database is ok because when i add a table it is generated successfully

Comment: thank you for information. It still doesn't work and I am stack :(

Comment: Updated my answer a bit again. I think i gave some bad information earlier about the if-statement, sorry about that. You should try using Blade's if, maybe that'll work. If not, what error does it return?